# How can I get current SharePoint site URL in PowerApps as a variable

Tags: sharepoint-online, powerapp

How can I get current SharePoint site URL in PowerApps as a variable?

Like `http://tenant.sharepoint.com/sites/siteName`

Comment: What do you mean by current SharePoint site? Are you customizing any form of SharePoint list or you are creating a stand alone app and adding SharePoint list as a data source??

Comment: i am creatin standalone , but i am able to get done by small workaround

Comment: What workaround you used? You can answer your own question and mention the workaround you used. It may help others.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you mean using flow in powerapps?

As far as I know, we can't pick the site url when setting the variable.

[image]